# Try to catch a click in a controller using dom selector

Tags: extjs

My problem is complex, so don't hesitate if you have questions  I would be more specifique.

I want to catch an event thru my controller.

I've got a simple view which contains only a template. This template contains a lot of link.

Here is the code of my view:

```
Ext.define('Application.view.suiviItems.suiviMenu', {

extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

alias: 'widget.suiviMenu',

id: 'suiviMenu',

layout: {
    type: 'border'
},

bodyCls: 'bodyMenu',

bodyPadding: '10 10 10 10',

title: 'Suivi',

tpl: [
    '<tpl for=".">',
    '    <div class="Main">',
    '        <div class="Gestion">',
    '            <ul>  ',
    '                <li>',
    '                    <span>',
    '                        <a id="pfp" href="#">Valeur du point FP</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">Référentiels</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">Valeur du taux de CAS</a><br/>',
    '                        <b>Paramètrage nationaux, ministériels et référentiels</b>',
    '                    </span>',
    '                </li>  ',
    '                <li>',
    '                    <span>',
    '                        <a href="#">Plafond d\'emploi</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">Plafond de crédit</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">Enveloppes</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">Mode de gestion des mouvements</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">Calcul des ratios</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">Corrections de consommation</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">Provisions pour mouvement</a><br/>',
    '                        <b>Paramètrage des exercices budgétaires</b>',
    '                    </span>',
    '                </li> ',
    '                <li>',
    '                    <span>',
    '                        <a href="#">Liste des mouvements</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">Prévoir un mouvement</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">Import en masse de mouvements</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">Rapprochement des mouvements prévus / constatés</a><br/>',
    '                        <b>Gestion des mouvements</b>',
    '                    </span>',
    '                </li>',
    '                <li>',
    '                    <span>',
    '                        <a href="#">Importer des dossiers de paye</a><br/>',
    '                        <b>Imports</b>',
    '                    </span>',
    '                </li>',
    '            </ul>',
    '        </div>',
    '        <div class="Restitution">',
    '            <ul>  ',
    '                <li>',
    '                    <span>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-01: Suivi N ETPT</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-03: Liste et impacts des mouvements</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-05: Suivi N</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-08: Suivi N agrégé</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-22: Prévisions, consommations et soldes des dépenses hors PSOP</a><br/>',
    '                        <b>Restitutions</b>',
    '                    </span>',
    '                </li>     ',
    '                                <li>',
    '                    <span>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-02: Vue agrégée de la dépense constatée</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-07: Vue agrégée de la consommation d\'emplois</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-04: Consommation constatée du plafond d\'emploi par catégorie statutaire</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-06: Consommation constatée du plafond d\'emploi par catégorie d\'emploi</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-13: Suivi de la dépense constatée par imputation budgétaire et par catégorie d\'emploi</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-14: Suivi de la dépense constatée par imputation budgétaire et par catégorie statutaire</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-15: Suivi de la dépense constatée par code élément et par catégorie d\'emploi</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-16: Suivi de la dépense constatée par code élément et par catégorie statutaire</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-20: Ratios</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-21: Données individuelles de paye par catégorie budgétaire</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-23: Coûts moyens</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-24: Restitution individuelle de paye</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-25: Suivi des codes éléments par agent</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-28: Consommations des crédits sous enveloppes</a><br/>',
    '                        <a href="#">RP-38: Consommations des provisions pour mouvements</a><br/>',
    '                        <b>Payes constatées</b>',
    '                    </span>',
    '                </li>',
    '            </ul>',
    '        </div>',
    '    </div>',
    '</tpl>',


],
```

});

Now I want to plug an event on each link, so I thought it will be useful to put them in my controller.

Here is the code of my controller:

```
Ext.define('Application.controller.suivi.suiviMenu', {
/**
 *
 */
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

views: [
    'Application.view.suiviItems.suiviMenu'
],

models: [

],

stores: [

],

init: function(){

    this.control({

        'pfp':{
            click: function(){
                console.log("Click 1");
            }
        },

        'span a': {
            click: function(c){
                console.log('Click 2')
            },
        },
    });
}
```

});

Do you know why my event is never triggered ?
If I did it with a wrong way, could anyone be kind to me and explain me how I supposed to do it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you read the docs for [control](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-control), you'll see that the selectors it accepts must be usable by `Ext.ComponentQuery` which involve selecting Ext components. You are using dom selectors to try to select actual HTML elements which will not work.

If you want to listen to clicks on these elements, you'll have to use a different method to get a reference to them. You could, for example, in an 'afterrender' listener use `panel.el.select('span a')` to get a reference to all the links and attach click listeners to each link element.

Comment: I've tried your idea but I think I didn't understood it completely